# Как сделать кнопки на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать кнопки на одном уровне?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://jsbin.com/deqecileke/3/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item button {
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <p>1</p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>title</p>      
    </div>
    <button>btn</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>2</p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quis aliquam hic corrupti eius sunt non quasi repellendus ducimus doloremque magni amet, molestiae error, porro facilis, similique modi eos! Cupiditate!</p>
    </div>    
    <button>btn</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте одинаковый размер блокам с текстом перед кнопкой или же прижмите обе кнопки к самому низу блока прописав для кнопок:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```